# Make CaptionText Bold in CaptionPanel gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I want to make the captionText in captionPanel as Bold.

CaptionPanel personalInfo = new CaptionPanel("Personal  Information");

I want to make the "Personal  Information" content as Bold like **Personal  Information** instead of Personal  Information.

Can Someone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a style class on the entire widget

```
CaptionPanel personalInfo = new CaptionPanel("Personal Information");
personalInfo.setStyleName("bold"); //bold is the name of a css class
```

Or if you want to style a part of the text, then you can write something like this

```
SafeHtml safeHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<div><span style="font-weight:bold">Personal</span> Information</div>");
CaptionPanel personalInfo = new CaptionPanel(safeHtml);
```

Comment: When I try writing  personalInfo. It doesnt show up setStyleName.

Comment: Make sure that your import for CaptionPanel is com.google.gwt.user.client.ui

Comment: Yes, I have 
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CaptionPanel;  Is there anything else I am missinghere

Comment: I could get setStyleName but it did not result in any changes. It was a regular text. Not a bold one

Comment: check with Firebug to see what's the result.